# Cant read a csv file in python because the file is not found

Tags: python, macos, csv, directory

I am trying to read a csv file in python, but I keep getting a "FileNotFoundError". No such file or directory

I have it written as:
file = open('case_study2.csv')

I used:

import os

os.getcwd()

to get the current directory for my python file which came back as:
runfile('/Users/natestewart/casestudy2/Task4_CaseStudy2', wdir='/Users/natestewart/casestudy2')

Answer (score 2):

To read csv files, one way is by using pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
path = '/Users/natestewart/casestudy2/Task4_CaseStudy2'
file = pd.read_csv('path/case_study2.csv')
```